# define new mimetype in navigator object

Tags: javascript

I would like to insert my mimeType i navigator object. 
I am trying this but no luck.

```
 window.navigator ={ mimeTypes: {(type:"application/myapp", description:"My description")} };
```

Please help

Answer (score 0):

Reading about [window.navigator at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.navigator):

> The Window.navigator read-only property returns a reference to the Navigator object, which can be queried for information about the application running the script.

Its **read-only**, you can't change its value.